# Register a name for each client in Named Pipe

Tags: c#, named-pipes

In Interprocess Communications, I have a PipeServer process that starts a NamedPipe and some other clients that connect to that and there is some message protocols to deal with.

In some cases i want to send a message from server to just one client.
So, Is there any way to register a name for each client when connected to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [List-Based Publish-Subscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx) pattern. What you have to do, is modify subscription call to include client ID, then store it in a list and when you want to announce to specific client, simply take the list element and use the callback. Something around the edges of below:

```
    public interface ISampleClientContract
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void AnnounceSomeStuff();
    }

    public class Subscriber
    {
        public ISampleClientContract Callback { get; set; }
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
    }

    private List<Subscriber> MyClients = new List<Subscriber>();

    public void Subscribe(Guid id)
    {
        MyClients.Add(new Subscriber
            { 
                Callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISampleClientContract>()
                ID = id
            });
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(Guid ID)
    {
        MyClients.Remove(o => o.ID == id).First());
    }

    public void NotifyClient(Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            MyClients.Where( o => o.ID == id).First().Callback.AnnounceSomeStuff();
        }
        catch
        {
            MyClients.Remove(MyClients.Where(o => o.ID == id).first()); //instance dead?
        }
    }

    public void AnnounceToAll()
    {
        MyClients.ForEach(o => o.Callback.AnnounceSomeStuff());
    }
```